# Calculating future date with strtotime doesn't work properly

Tags: php

If I run "next saturday" into strtotime function it shows 4/3/2010 as the date. Why does it not show 4/10?

Comment: of course now at 12:03AM on 4/3 it shows 4/10.

Comment: This is not a problem. It is correct. "this saturday" is 4/3/2010.

Comment: ugh, sorry that's supposed to say "next saturday."

Comment: `strtotime` returns a timestamp, not formatted dates.

Comment: correct, I parsed it using date()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

got it ...

```
strtotime('next Saturday', strtotime('+1 day'));
```

Comment: @luckytaxi - What timezone are you in?

Comment: im on the east coast, I used "America/New_York"

Comment: Look at the answer I provided.

Answer (score 1):

[Other Timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php)

```
date_default_timezone_set("Etc/GMT-5");
$time = strtotime('Saturday +7 day');
$date = date("m/d/Y",$time);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

or edit your php.ini